# Kafka Application Log Configuration

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

I'm trying to move the application/Log4J logs for Apache Kafka (not the data logs). This has become exceptionally hard to research as there are many log related terms with regards to Kafka. I've opened the log4j.properties, and found that the logs are written to: `${kafka.logs.dir}` however, I'm not sure where to change `kafka.logs.dir`. We need to change this location due to low disk space on our VMs.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is to override the environment property `LOG_DIR` prior launching the kafka server, for example in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka
echo 'Kafka application logs set to ' $LOG_DIR
./kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon  /kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/server.properties
```

You can also override the `log4j.properties` with your own see `kafka-server-start.sh` (snippet from `1.1.0`):

```
if [ "x$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$base_dir/../config/log4j.properties"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very simple.

Answer (score 4):

The log4J log directory has to be passed via the following JVM property:

```
-Dkafka.logs.dir=/some/path
```

If you're using the `kafka-server-start.sh` to start your broker, you can just export `LOG_DIR` and that will [automatically](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L197) set the JVM property for you

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the JVM property

```
-Dkafka.logs.dir=/some/path
```

Or the environnement variable `$LOG_DIR`

The former is set to the latter in `kafka-run-class.sh` which is called by `kafka-server-start.sh`

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1560c5bd7e556ca6c0f49934b5ad3542ed6208fb/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L243